# Width of text in amsbook

Tags: margins, amsbook

I am writing my master thesis as `amsbook` and I am not quite satisfied with the width of my text. It is not wide enough. Does someone know whether you can change the width?

Comment: Thank you! I solved the problem now, using:  \usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, left = …cm, right = …cm, top = …cm, bottom = …cm=}

Comment: If this is a master's, your graduate school almost certainly specifies the width they want somewhere so the question really is what satisfies them.

Answer (score 4):

The `geometry` package is the standard way of adjusting page layout for LaTeX.

> The pack­age pro­vides an easy and flex­i­ble user in­ter­face to cus­tomize page lay­out, im­ple­ment­ing auto-cen­ter­ing and auto-bal­anc­ing mech­a­nisms so that the users have only to give the least de­scrip­tion for the page lay­out. For ex­am­ple, if you want to set each mar­gin 2cm with­out header space, what you need is just `\usep­a­ck­age[mar­gin=2cm,no­head]{ge­om­e­try}`.
>
> The pack­age knows about all the stan­dard pa­per sizes, so that the user need not know what the nom­i­nal ‘real’ di­men­sions of the pa­per are, just its stan­dard name (such as `a4`, `let­ter`, etc.).
>
> An im­por­tant fea­ture is the pack­age’s abil­ity to com­mu­ni­cate the pa­per size it's set up to the out­put (whether via DVI `\spe­cial`s or via di­rect in­ter­ac­tion with PDF(LA)TEX).

The CTAN package page is located [here](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry).

Answer (score 4):

With `amsbook` you should do

```
\setlength{\textwidth}{12cm} % or whatever length you want
\calclayout
```

Comment: Could you talk about why this is the preferred solution over @ChrisS 's solution below? As I read your two answers combined, ChrisS describes the generally preferred solution, but in the specific case of `amsbook`, one should use yours. Why is this special to `amsbook`? Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @JasonHemann AMS Book docs explicitly state that geometry package should be avoided. Docclasses in general fiddle with output on low level, so bypassing them is a sure way to break things.